# Asus Zenbook 3 UX390U 16.04 no sound headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

Sound is a bit scratchy through speakers. It worked on headphones (also was little scratchy), but now it does not. It works perfectly on Windows though. Howerer, on Ubuntu I can hear 'bump' in headphones when I plug them in, mute and unmute.
Spotify (nor any other app) does not output there though. It does through speakers. I think output port works fine, but apps don't redirect their sound there.
Headphones are connected to laptop directly. Speakers are built-in.

[AlsaMixer and PulseAudio screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtYmo.jpg).

Edit1:
I should note, that i do have ASUS universal dock plugged in.

```
➜  ~ pactl list short sinks
0       alsa_output.usb-ASUS_ASUS_USB_Audio_00000000-00.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
1       alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo      module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       RUNNING
```

[Here's the `pactl list sink-inputs` output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24917312/).

Edit2: Moved info from comments to the post.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `pactl list short sinks` and `pactl list sink-inputs` *while Spotify is playing*? You can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Done. [Link to station](https://www.asus.com/Laptops-Accessory/Universal-Dock/specifications/) - my rep is too low to paste >2 links in post.

Comment: I see that your system has two audio devices. Are the speakers and the headphones connected to the same device?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question.  I have ASUS universal dock plugged in through usb-c. It has jack port, but the port does not work at all under Ubuntu. Laptop has it's own speakers.

Comment: If the speakers are internal, are the headphones plugged directly into the laptop? I'd presume so if you say that the audio jack in USB dock doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. Speakers are internal. Headphones plugged in directly.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, headphones works great on Windows.  [Pulseaudio screens](http://imgur.com/a/FygNK).

Comment: I have no further idea to resolve or investigate this issue at this moment. Could you please [edit] your post to add the relevant information from your comments? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.